# Align image left of title and paragraph then between them in small screens

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a block of heading and text + image where:
- In large screens, they will alternate left and right.
- In smaller screens, the image will be below the heading and above the paragraph text.

[This is an example of how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuBKg.jpg)

I tried using a flexbox but the heading and text wouldn't play along nicely. I tried inline-block, but the image wouldn't vertical-align in the wrapper.

I'm adding this to a squarespace website and the template doesn't use bootstrap, so I cannot use that.

```html
<div class="alternating-content-block even">
  <div class="heading">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/56099b28e4b0e9a8dd53c467/1474681761217-VA1F29OQYAQX8IIW1018/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kFNHtaRIWeOk0XtEG2Iz2ptZw-zPPgdn4jUwVcJE1ZvWhcwhEtWJXoshNdA9f1qD7Xj1nVWs2aaTtWBneO2WM-tqmpERyOMWWNh4XLI3lmIESCawszvU15S2rzqX3HdiIw/image-asset.jpeg?format=300w" />
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer venenatis posuere urna et sagittis. In elit elit, venenatis quis leo ut, accumsan lobortis arcu. Donec ut ultricies lorem. Donec id eleifend ipsum. In mi massa, lacinia non facilisis at, vehicula eget purus. Pellentesque dui dolor, scelerisque at ultrices at, fermentum sit amet dui. Mauris posuere gravida ornare. Sed id consectetur lorem. Integer pulvinar mi sed mi dignissim blandit. Vestibulum aliquet ex elit, vitae condimentum nibh faucibus id. Aliquam rhoncus risus non turpis pulvinar, vitae eleifend turpis eleifend. Etiam sed mi eget lorem pharetra imperdiet id ut est. Praesent mollis suscipit velit pharetra posuere. In in accumsan nisl.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="alternating-content-block odd">
  <div class="heading">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/56099b28e4b0e9a8dd53c467/1474681761217-VA1F29OQYAQX8IIW1018/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kFNHtaRIWeOk0XtEG2Iz2ptZw-zPPgdn4jUwVcJE1ZvWhcwhEtWJXoshNdA9f1qD7Xj1nVWs2aaTtWBneO2WM-tqmpERyOMWWNh4XLI3lmIESCawszvU15S2rzqX3HdiIw/image-asset.jpeg?format=300w" />
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer venenatis posuere urna et sagittis. In elit elit, venenatis quis leo ut, accumsan lobortis arcu. Donec ut ultricies lorem. Donec id eleifend ipsum. In mi massa, lacinia non facilisis at, vehicula eget purus. Pellentesque dui dolor, scelerisque at ultrices at, fermentum sit amet dui. Mauris posuere gravida ornare. Sed id consectetur lorem. Integer pulvinar mi sed mi dignissim blandit. Vestibulum aliquet ex elit, vitae condimentum nibh faucibus id. Aliquam rhoncus risus non turpis pulvinar, vitae eleifend turpis eleifend. Etiam sed mi eget lorem pharetra imperdiet id ut est. Praesent mollis suscipit velit pharetra posuere. In in accumsan nisl.
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.alternating-content-block {
    position: relative;
  }
  .alternating-content-block .text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 66%;
  }
  .alternating-content-block .heading {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 66%;
  }
  .alternating-content-block .image {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33%;
  }

  .alternating-content-block.even .text, 
  .alternating-content-block.even .heading  {
    float: left;

  }
  .alternating-content-block.even .image {
    float: right;
  }

  .alternating-content-block.odd .text, 
  .alternating-content-block.odd .heading  {
    float: right;
  }
  .alternating-content-block.odd .image {
    float: left;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use `float` (left or right, as needed)  on the images, place them before the text in the HTML code and have a media query for small screens that changes the image CSS to `float: none; display: block;`to display it in its own block (by default 100% wide) above the text.